# Represent a product taxonomy in database

Tags: database-design, tree

I have to represent a complex product taxonomy having parent and child relationship in a database. Can someone guide me on doing this??

For e.g. the root may be 'All Product' 
then may be at the second level we have 'computers' and 'furniture'
like a tree??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a simple tree example using SQL Server 2005:

```
--go through a nested table supervisor - user table and display the chain
DECLARE @Contacts table (id varchar(6), first_name varchar(10), reports_to_id varchar(6))
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('1','Jerome', NULL )  -- tree is as follows:
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('2','Joe'   ,'1')     --                      1-Jerome
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('3','Paul'  ,'2')     --                     /        \
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('4','Jack'  ,'3')     --              2-Joe           9-Bill
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('5','Daniel','3')     --            /       \              \
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('6','David' ,'2')     --     3-Paul          6-David       10-Sam
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('7','Ian'   ,'6')     --    /      \            /    \
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('8','Helen' ,'6')     -- 4-Jack  5-Daniel   7-Ian    8-Helen
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('9','Bill ' ,'1')     --
INSERT @Contacts VALUES ('10','Sam'  ,'9')     --

DECLARE @Root_id  char(4)

--get 2 and below
SET @Root_id=2
PRINT '@Root_id='+COALESCE(''''+@Root_id+'''','null')
;WITH StaffTree AS
(
    SELECT 
        c.id, c.first_name, c.reports_to_id, c.reports_to_id as Manager_id, cc.first_name AS Manager_first_name, 1 AS LevelOf
        FROM @Contacts                  c
            LEFT OUTER JOIN @Contacts  cc ON c.reports_to_id=cc.id
        WHERE c.id=@Root_id OR (@Root_id IS NULL AND c.reports_to_id IS NULL)
    UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            s.id, s.first_name, s.reports_to_id, t.id, t.first_name, t.LevelOf+1
        FROM StaffTree            t
            INNER JOIN @Contacts  s ON t.id=s.reports_to_id
    WHERE s.reports_to_id=@Root_id OR @Root_id IS NULL OR t.LevelOf>1
)
SELECT * FROM StaffTree
```

output:

```
@Root_id='2   '
id     first_name reports_to_id Manager_id Manager_first_name LevelOf
------ ---------- ------------- ---------- ------------------ -----------
2      Joe        1             1          Jerome             1
3      Paul       2             2          Joe                2
6      David      2             2          Joe                2
7      Ian        6             6          David              3
8      Helen      6             6          David              3
4      Jack       3             3          Paul               3
5      Daniel     3             3          Paul               3

(7 row(s) affected)
```

change @Root_id to get different output:

```
@Root_id=null
id     first_name reports_to_id Manager_id Manager_first_name LevelOf
------ ---------- ------------- ---------- ------------------ -----------
1      Jerome     NULL          NULL       NULL               1
2      Joe        1             1          Jerome             2
9      Bill       1             1          Jerome             2
10     Sam        9             9          Bill               3
3      Paul       2             2          Joe                3
6      David      2             2          Joe                3
7      Ian        6             6          David              4
8      Helen      6             6          David              4
4      Jack       3             3          Paul               4
5      Daniel     3             3          Paul               4

(10 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Not a very good example of design though. No keys or RI and all the columns are nullable.

Comment: @dportas, I did say `simple tree example`. This provides a much better basic understanding of the issue than only suggesting to "google" search of the topic (like you do in your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335971/represent-a-product-taxonomy-in-database/4336114#4336114).

Answer (score 1):

Each record has a parent id. It refers to another record in the same table.

The root element has parent id NULL.
Naturally, this would better be indexed.

In some usages, it is efficient to also have a record point to its first direct sibling.

Comment: Thanks All of you who help on this topic

Answer (score 1):

I would start by determining if you are going to have a fixed, predetrmined number of levels in your tree or if you need to dynamically add levels.

In the former case then one structure might be a simple set of tables such as 'product _superclass', 'product_class & 'product'. product_class could havae a foreign key to product_class, and product could have a foreign key referencing product_class.

If you don't know the number of levels then you may only need a single table (assuming any product only has a single parent). In this case each row could optionally refer to a parent in the same table.

A fixed number of levels may make for easier, more readable queries with obvisouly reduced flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a "single best" answer for this with the question you're stating.

You might want to avoid trapping yourself into a Parent / Child relationship in separate tables (two or more) as things get messy almost immediately.

Consider using the more generic "Product" table - and allow this to ref to Parent value (ID of another Product record).

Best to model this out a bit -

but it can break into "Structures", "Products (Styles)", then SKUs (sellable items having inventory). -- SKUs can sometimes further breakdown into UPCs (EANs) over time depending on the product types (Groceries for example offer multiple UPCs to SKUs for seasonal rotations).

Note - attribution to any level is then possible against the appropriate ID and suddenly you've got access to these attributes up the line for inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different ways to manage trees in SQL. Joe Celko wrote a whole book on the topic which you might want to take a look at. You can Google for plenty of examples online.

Answer (score 1):

If you can move to SQL Server 2008 and use the new hiearchy data type.  This [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) starts the tutorial.  The code to work with the hiearchy data type is much cleaner.  If you cannot go with 2K8 then parent/child from KM works well.